# Windows10, A form's width size seems like keeping 1.25 times larger when I open the form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I want to restore the form's size and I used the below codes.

I got an idea from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873658/net-windows-forms-remember-windows-size-and-location).

And I found out on some machines (in particular, Windows10) a form's width keeps doubled when I reopen this specific form.

I'm guessing that it might be scaling issue of screen resolution but I can't reproduce it.

Since I didn't calculate but store the form's size directly, I have no idea where to look.

I'm going to use a remote assistant and try to figure out why it happened. I will share what I find.

```cs
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.RestoreWindowPosition();
}

private void SaveWindowPosition()
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.ReviewFormState = this.WindowState;

    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.ReviewFormLocation = this.Location;
        Properties.Settings.Default.ReviewFormSize = this.Size;
    }
    else
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.ReviewFormLocation = this.RestoreBounds.Location;
        Properties.Settings.Default.ReviewFormSize = this.RestoreBounds.Size;
    }

    Properties.Settings.Default.ReviewFormHasSetDefaults = true;

    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

private void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    this.SaveWindowPosition();
}

private void RestoreWindowPosition()
{
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.ReviewFormHasSetDefaults)
    {
        this.WindowState = Properties.Settings.Default.ReviewFormState;
        this.Location = Properties.Settings.Default.ReviewFormLocation;
        this.Size = Properties.Settings.Default.ReviewFormSize;
    }
}
```

### After a remote session

As I said earlier, I finished a remote session. I found out this is because of a scale issue. But still, it seems pretty strange. I've checked [display settings - scale and layout] menu and it was 125%. Then I open the form and repeat. I found the form size is growing. I think it was 1.25 times on the first try. What I did was I changed the scale on 100%, then did the same thing open and repeat. For this time, I didn't find anything; the form was in the same size.

**My middle step conclusion** is that I need to save a pure size of the form. I will translate according to the scale. Then I guess, I can get a real size of the form. I'm not really sure I will try and share what I find for letting someone out in the loop.

@Jimi and @Louis Go
I hope that one day I can help you too. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: If you have win10 environment, try to tweaking "Display Settings" -> "Change the size of text, apps". It might reproduce your problem.

Comment: Make your application DpiAware if haven't. Start from here: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103), then take a look at the app.config settings and to [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms#configuring-your-windows-forms-app-for-high-dpi-support) (consider and test the `PerMonitorV2` setup). Take into consideration the Form's `AutoScaleMode`. See the difference between `Dpi` and `Font`.

Answer (score 0):

Jimi:

> Make your application DpiAware if haven't. Start from here: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e/13228495#13228495), then take a look at the app.config settings and to [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms#configuring-your-windows-forms-app-for-high-dpi-support) (consider and test the `PerMonitorV2` setup). Take into consideration the Form's `AutoScaleMode`. See the difference between `Dpi` and `Font`.